# Deconvolution of sinc function in spectrum calculation in FTS

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, domain-decomposition, signal-processing, convolution

In Fourier transform spectroscopy (FTS) I am calculating a broadband interferogram (e.m. frequency 190-300 GHz top-hat), then back-retrieving the spectrum by FT.
Here in the figure, you can see the result: I expect the retrieved spectrum to be the same as the "injected" one but there is the effect of the top-hat bandpass.

[image]

How do I correct the top-hat bandpass in python?
I suspect I need to deconvolve the bandpass function with the spectrum (or the interferogram). As shown in the following figure example, the FT of the sinc function (the result of the bandpass gives the same effect).

[image]

Comment: Just checking but are you aware of this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon

Comment: @PC1 you found the issue, I will try to adopt different apodizations